# GCP Machine Images - fetch list of images for project

Tags: java, spring, http, google-cloud-platform

I have a JAVA application that includes creating VM instances in GCP.

I now am attempting to use the new "machine images" functionality in order to be able to replicate whole instances (as opposed to using the images from disk option).

I am using the beta api to create images from instances, however I need to be able to then fetch a list of these machine-images back to my application in order for them to be used to create new instances.

I am looking for some GET api for this purpose, but
I cannot find documentation on this anywhere. any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/machineImages/get) you can get list of machine images within a project.

Comment: I think you meant this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/machineImages/list